# Fragmenting a huge table

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I currently am working on some project that insert a lot of data into some tables. To ensure that my system is fast enough, I want to fragment my huge table into some smaller tables representing the months data. I have an idea of how it will work, but I still need some more informations.

The primary keys of my tables must be continuous so I thought of an architecture that would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
    `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
}

CREATE TABLE `foo012014` (
    `id` bigint(11),
    `description` varchar(255),
}

CREATE TABLE `foo022014` (
    `id` bigint(11),
    `description` varchar(255),
}
```

On every insertion, the PHP page will look if a table already exists for the month and if not will create it.

The thing is, how do I get to bind the "foo" child table primary key to the "foo" mother table? Plus, is this design a bad practice or is it good?

Comment: IMHO it is a bad idea to name your table with "foo012014", cos firstly, you want to create a table for each month? Create tables that are more generic such as foo and fooMonth only ... that in the table fooMonth have a column that store the date and have foo_id that will be id of Foo it belogns to. You can elaborate on that then ...

Comment: Unless you're using sharding, this is an incredibly bad idea for performance... what happens when you need to do a query across months? or a comparison of different months? if your table is properly indexed, then you can handle billions of rows, size is __not__ going to be an issue; if it's badly indexed, then the solution is to index it properly, not to spread a bad structure across multiple tables

Comment: How many lines we are talking about? What kind of database?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers! Can someone explain me what exactly is sharding? From what I read it is an architecture that allow to split the table data in multiple tables. What is the main purpose of sharding?

The user will only see the data from the last 3 months and I can have up to a million rows every month in each tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good pratice, and difficult your queries.

With just the id you already have an index, which allows for better indexing of your data.

If your queries are also nicely written and organized, the time to execute a query in your database will be relatively small with 1 million rows or 20.

## Solutions

### First

For a better maintenance I recommend the following:

- Add a new field in your table `food`: `created datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (works in MySQL 5.6+, for other versions, or set manually in every insert, or change to `timestamp`)

And, just use this field for group your data basead in datetime values, like that: `2014-01-24 13:18`.

It's easy to select and manipulate.

### Second

Create a external table with `month` and `year`, like that:

```
drop table if exists foo_periods;
create table foo_periods (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  month smallint(4) not null,
  year smallint(4) not null,
  created datetime,
  modified datetime,
  active boolean not null default 1,
  index foo_periods_month (month),
  index foo_periods_year (year)
);
```

You can change `smallint` in month to `varchar` if you feels better.

Then, just create a `FK`, and done!

```
ALTER TABLE foo 
  ADD COLUMN foo_period_id int not null;

ALTER TABLE foo
    ADD CONSTRAINT foo_foo_period_id
    FOREIGN KEY (foo_period_id)
    REFERENCES foo_periods (id);
```

## References

If you want read more about **fragmentation / optimization** in MySQL, [this is a great post](http://blog.softlayer.com/2011/mysql-slow-check-for-fragmentation/).